# Reliable remote control of Android Device over the Internet

Tags: remote-control, remote-access

I am looking for RELIABLE ways to control an Android tablet remotely (Currently un-rooted, but I will root it if needed).

Preferably full gui, like Teamviewer, and something simpler in addition.

I have tried Teamviewer, but I do not trust it.

The tablet uses both 4G and Wi-Fi connection.
Normal home Wi-Fi connections.

Comment: You could use VNC but this may not work via 4G (requires an open port and port-forwarding). If you don't trust Teamviewer, then your solutions outside your own network are kind of limited.

Comment: I don't know so much networking, but I guess it should be something "connecting out" from the device to a central server.  Like tv probably does.  Think a VPN + VNC could work.

Comment: Yes, a VPN will work, given that your cell provider does normal routing and not some weird back and forth that prevents VPN connections (NAT is okay but I have seen things that just prevent you from anything but HTTP).

Comment: Splashtop. Though non-LAN connections require monthly subscriptions, the graphics and performance are more satisfactory than TeamViewer. Also blazingly fast under LAN.

Comment: @andy: The main issue is reliability.  If I have a reliable connection I can install more performant solutions on top.